# How do I setOnItemClickListener correctly in a non-activity class that populates a ListView from an Activity Class

Tags: java, android

My ListView is created dynamically from a HashMap depending on what the user enters into an EditText in a non-activity class. The reason why I believe it is to do with the setOnItemClickListener is because it works when I set the ListView values manually in the Activity class in the OnCreate method.
The non-activity class contains a couple of methods for such as AsyncTask and a recursion method.

Activity Class

```
public class WordEntry extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {

//Variable's Declared

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.word_entry);

    /*Code for reading values into HashMap here*/

    btn_Resolve = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_word);
    btn_Resolve.setOnClickListener(this);

    //TODO Make list item's clickable.

    spin_options = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_choose_resolver_type);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spin_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.resolver_options, R.layout.simpler_spinner_item);

    spin_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin_options.setAdapter(spin_adapter);
    lv_words = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_word_display);

    /*This following two lines were a test to see if manually setting the adapter worked, it did. */
    //lv_words.setAdapter(spin_adapter);
    //lv_words.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Log.i("HelloListView", "You clicked item: " + parent + " at position: " + position);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.submit_word:

            edt_WordEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.word_entry_textbox);
            word = edt_WordEntry.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
            boolean space_found = matcher.find();
            View hideKey = this.getCurrentFocus();

            if (space_found) {
               edt_WordEntry.setText(R.string.no_spaces_allowed);

            } else {
                ResolveWord fixAnagram = new ResolveWord(word, this,wordHashSet);
                ResolveAllWords fixAnagramAll = new ResolveAllWords(word,this,wordHashSet);

                /*The following two lines are two other methods that I tried during debugging to try get it working. Separately of                  course and this debugging was for when the spinner was set to something other than "Anagram's"*/
                //fixAnagramAll.lv_words.setOnItemClickListener(new ResolveWord(word,this,wordHashSet));  
                //lv_words.setOnItemClickListener(new ResolveWord(word,this,wordHashSet));                           
                if(spin_options.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Anagram;s")) {
                    hideKeyboard(this);
                    fixAnagram.execute();
                } else {
                    hideKeyboard(this);
                    fixAnagramAll.execute();
                }
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Non Activity Class

```
public class ResolveWord extends  AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<String>> implements OnItemClickListener {

 /*Variable's Declared*/


public ResolveWord(String letters, Activity wordEntryContext, HashSet<String> passedHashSet) {
    /*Variables initiated */

}


   /*Some code.....*/

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> wordSuccess) {

    /*Code which puts data into an arraylist so I can put into the array adadater that follows...*/

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(thisContext,R.layout.lv_displaywrods_wordentry,
            wordSuccess);

    //Ways I tried to get the ListView clickable in the non-activity class...
    lv_words.setAdapter(adapter);

    //lv_words.setOnItemClickListener(new WordEntry());
    //lv_words.setOnItemClickListener(this);

   /*lv_words.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //I have a break point here to see if the string gets assigned during debugging after clicking a rowitem.
        String x = "Test";

    }
});*/

    //This always returns false
    boolean o = lv_words.hasOnClickListeners();
    //This always returns true
    boolean p = lv_words.isClickable();


}
```

On top of the above code I also made some edits shortly ago when I thought I had it solved and created an `onItemClickListener` in the activity class in the onCreate method and assigned this a value using `getOnItemClickListener`. I then passed it to the non-activity class through the constructor but this also failed to work.

Comment: It really hard to understand what are you asking. There is no any connection of activity class and setting on click listener. In your code you don't set click listener, it's commented out. Could you show your real code without all that comments and so on and try to formulate your question in understandable way?

Comment: @Divers all the code that is commented out is steps that I had tested through debugging that didn't work. I kept them in place just as a reminder of what I have already tested. The connection of the activity class and the non-activity class comes through calling the `.execute` method to start the `AsyncTask` process.  It's simple really - I proceed to the non-activity class successfully, reach the onPostExecute method, try to set `onItemClickListener` and that then fails. edit: It doesn't fail as in gives an error, it just doesn't respond to clicks.

Comment: @COYH how did you check that click listener doesn't get click events? What are you checking `lv_words.hasOnClickListeners();` is if there `ClickListener`, not `ItemClickListener` which is absolutely different thing.

Comment: @Divers for starters, as a test when I manually set entries into the ListView when I hover over the text they highlight with a black shadow, I can provide a video if you want. _What are you checking lv_words.hasOnClickListeners(); is if there ClickListener, not ItemClickListener which is absolutely different thing._ if this is correct then fair enough, but I also have methods that the onItemClick event or whatever is suppose to proceed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes, ArrayAdapter uses the toString() method of each entry in the ArrayList (or array) supplied to it and populates the layout specified in the second argument of the constructor you have used.

If wordSuccess array list is not empty, then your mapping of the entry to this layout is failing. ArrayAdapter expects a TextView or something that is a derivative of that as the second argument in that constructor. Your lv_displaywords_wordentry layout file is likely not a straightforward TextView or it contains a TextView wrapped with some kind of a ViewGroup container. Since you are displaying simple list items, I would recommend you use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 and if your array list is not empty you should see the words showing up.

**EDIT:**

As I guessed, from the comments, I understand you are trying to pass the layout that resolves to a ListView instead of a TextView in your ArrayAdapter. You can use the ListView normally but your adapter has no way of mapping the String entry in the array list to the ListView object (as the ListView represents the entire collection while mapping is done on a one to one basis). This is why you need to pass a TextView (or a custom subclass or variation of it). Use the android supplied list item layout and you should get a standard TextView.

Comment: I suspect you're correct. I'm going to try find some substitutes for `lv_displaywords_wordentry`and see what happens.

Comment: On the android developer pages `ArrayAdapter(Context context, **int resource**, int textViewResourceId)` the `lv_displaywords_wordentry` is the ListView which is working correctly since the words that are found are placed successfully in the `ListView` they are just unclickable.  (Obviously clickable is set to true in the xml file.)

Comment: I get it now - it is just as I suspected. You are passing a layout which resolves to a ListView while the adapter is expecting a TextView. The file will work correctly when used directly as a ListView. Your ArrayAdapter cannot map it though. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @uscunil This sounds hopeful, I'm expecting big things in the answer edit, because I'm unsure if what exactly to replace the second parameter with.

Comment: For the second parameter use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1. that should do the trick

Comment: bloody well brilliant, I can confirm that it is responding to the click events, I could hug you man. I will accept this as the answer, as soon as I am allowed I think I have to wait 24 hr's.- I was way off track and would have never found that,

Answer (score 1):

In the `AsyncTask` you can set `OnClickListeners` in the `onPostExecute` method and one the `onPreExecute` method. 

You cannot add `OnClickListener` or do any UI operations in the `doInBackground` method, since there you are making the network operations.

So you can set the `OnClickListener` regullary:

```
lv_words.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        // Do some coding...
    }
});
```

Comment: I have it set in the `OnPostExecture` method. It is commented out in the code sample I provided because I was debugging in other ways and was wary in case that had an effect so I made it redundant.

Comment: You suppose to do it there, unless you wish to do that in your `onCreate` method. The `AsyncTask` is still inside the activity, and you can do there UI operations but not on the `doInBackground` method.

Comment: Right, thanks for clearing that up. Going to try implement it.

Comment: Put that code you provided into the `onPostExecute` method. It just needed a slight edit because it is `setOnItemClickListener`. Still no joy though `boolean o = lv_words.hasOnClickListeners();` returns false & the items remain unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make setter for *ResolveWord* for passing *WordEntry* object - wordEntry to *ResolveWord* and in *onPostExecute(...)* write:  *lv_words.setOnItemClickListener(wordEntry);*

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand you, but I think you are going to archive following thing:

```
public class ResolveWord extends  AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<String>> {
    private Activity wordEntryContext;

   public ResolveWord(String letters, Activity wordEntryContext, HashSet<String> passedHashSet) {
       this.wordEntryContext = wordEntryContext;
       /*Other variables initiated */ 
   } 

   @Override 
   protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> wordSuccess) {
       // your code
       lv_words.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener)wordEntryContext); 
   }

}
```

Comment: I will test this out. Cheers.